# 1.2/50 us Combinational Wave Generator (Surge Test) Simulation - Help Needed

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice, waveform, configuration, surge

I am looking for assistance in editing my LTspice simulation for the design mentioned in the title. I have provided the design and output (open + short circuit) expectations (First two screenshots), as well as screenshots my own design and outputs that I observed. Please note that my design is supposed to be an exact replica of the schematic found in this link here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8094638.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the 1.2us means rise and 50us is accomplished by the circuit. The problem is you need the appropriate step input.

Try editing the PWL file to have a 1us step input:

[image]

Edit:
In the image it shows 0.1 and 0.2 for the time in the table, it should say 0.1u and 0.2u